# CSS orientation media query

Tags: css, media-queries

Can some one explain to me what the `orientation` media feature does in layman's terms?

Answer (score 3):

It's mainly for mobile devices like a phone. You can control the style based on whether the device is being held upright, or sideways ...

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait)
{
  /* Your CSS here */
}
```

```
@media all and (orientation:landscape)
{
  /* Your CSS here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are asking about the media attribute in the link tag please find the answer below.

Media is to tell the browser or the device to pick the right stylesheet for that particular device or an action.

Eg. if a style sheet is linked with media as Print the stylesheet will work only when the page is been printed. This way you can minimise the graphic and media involved in the page for print purposes.

in simple terms it is a if conditions for stylesheet.

you have the following media types.

Screen - obviously computer browser screen.
ttv - teletype
tv- television
projection - projectors
handheld - small screen handheld devices
print - for printer
braille - Braille feedback devices
aural - Speech synths
all - picks the same stylesheets for all the above.

Hope this helps...